# Oracle Apex dynamic action in tabular form. with vaildation

Tags: forms, oracle, oracle-apex, master-detail

APEX version  4.2.6.00.03

I have a Master/ Detail table. But I need to vaildate the detail table against the Master tables dates. 
Currently I use a PL/SQL expression below to validate against each the start_date and end_date in the master form. But this is done on submit. This is fine for the master form as only one instance.

```
CASE WHEN :Master_END_DATE >= :Master_Start_DATE OR
     :Master_END_DATE is NULL THEN TRUE
     ELSE FALSE
 END;
```

But in the detail there could be upto 20+ rows. So some type of live check/onchange validation. But in the tabular detail form you can not access any of the items from with a dynamic action.

- Detail_Start_date >= Master_start_Date
- Detail_Start_date <= Master_End_Date
- Detail_End_date >= Master_start_Date
- Detail_date <= Master_End_Date
- Detail_Start_date >= Detail_End_date
- Detail_End_date <= Detail_Start_Date

Please see below a snapshot of the form 
[image]

Is this even possible many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class to your Tabular Form Columns in Tabular Form:

[image: Edit your column]
[image: Add a class]

for the sake of this example I assign "xDate" class to my column. You should assign a class name to each of your column.

Then you create a Dynamic Action (for each class: startDate/endDate, in my case I create one for my column):

[image]

[image]

If you just need to make some validations with the fields you have in the screen you probably can make them with js only but that depend of what you want/need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: if you could do screen shots that would be most helpful